# drawBitmap nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, drawbitmap

this is my class..  ı want to use it in my simple game's `GameEngine`..  but ı didn't understand the problem here.. it doesn't work..

```
public class Droid {

    private Bitmap      bitmap; 
    private int     x;      
    private int     y;      
    private boolean         touched;    
    private Speed       speed;
    private Paint       paint;

    public Droid(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y)
        {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            // create droid and load bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                    R.drawable.droid_1);

        }

              public void draw(Canvas canvas)
        {

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                    y- bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
        }



     }
```

when ı run code, ı see a `nullpointerexception` at `draw()` method... how can ı solve this? thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// ı hope, ı solved this problem..  finally..  :)

public class Droid {

```
private Bitmap      bitmap; 
private int     x;      
private int     y;      
private boolean         touched;    
private Speed       speed;
private Paint       paint;

public Droid(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y)
    {
        paint= new Paint();
//    this.bitmap = bitmap;   // delete this part, it will work..  :)))
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

        // create droid and load bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                R.drawable.droid_1);

    }

          public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                y- bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    MyView mv = new MyView(this,bmp,100,100); 
            // pass the bitmap and x and y co-ordinates to the constructor of Myview
    setContentView(mv); // set the content to your activity
}
  }
```

Custom view class

```
  public class MyView extends View{ // should extend view
 Context c;
 private Bitmap   bitmap; 
 private int     x;      
 private int     y; 
 private Paint       paint;
 public MyView(Context context,Bitmap bmp, int i, int j) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c=context;
    this.bitmap=bmp;
    this.x=i;
    this.y=j;
    paint= new Paint();
}
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) // override view on draw and draw the bitmap
    {

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
             y- bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint); // instead of paint you can have null
    }
}
```

Comment: ı tried this:  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                y- bitmap.getHeight() / 2, null); but it tdidnt work..

Comment: thanks for your help..  ı try to understand your code..  public class Droid is not an extended view class..  so it maybe a problem for me..  if ı can solve, ı will come back...

Comment: you have to extend the view and override on draw to draw the bitmap on canvas. Also you can get the bitmap in your activity class and pass the bitmap object to the constructor of your custom view class.